# how to sort an object by date string as key - python

Tags: python

I have the object:

```
{'2017-10-2': 0.09457282561051072, '2017-10-3': 0.06606813446091735, '2017-10-1': 0.13701336286945082, '2017-10-6': 0.08511672971024725 }
```

And would like to sort it by date ( but the type of keys is string, not datetime ).
The response should like like:

```
{   
    '2017-10-1': 0.13701336286945082,
    '2017-10-2': 0.09457282561051072, 
    '2017-10-3': 0.06606813446091735, 
    '2017-10-6': 0.08511672971024725 
}
```

Was trying to find something using google ,but unsuccessfully.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: you can find ways to sort python dictionaries here: http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-sort-python-dictionaries-by-key-or-value/

Comment: Isn't `sorted(d)` enough? Python is sorting after the bytevalue of a char and so `'0'<'1'<'9'` in this case it works just fine.

Comment: Dictionaries are not sorted. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27262266/dictionary-is-not-staying-in-order-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionary can't be sorted, for that you have to use *OrderedDict* from *collections* module.

For datetime comparsion, you can use *dateutils.parse*

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
from collections import OrderedDict

d = {'2017-10-2': 0.09457282561051072, '2017-10-3': 0.06606813446091735, '2017-10-1': 0.13701336286945082, '2017-10-6': 0.08511672971024725}
print(OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: parse(x[0]))))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Everything works great